# Random distribution of byte arrays into one byte array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, byte

The problem I need to face right now is that I have a certain amount of bytearrays with different sizes. I want to put them into one single bytearray that is way larger than all the other bytearrays together so that voids occur inside of this large bytearray where no bytes have been put in.

The bytearrays are distributed randomly over the large bytearray but no bytearray may collide with another bytearray that has already been put there.
Is there an efficient why to do this random distribution without collisions?

Comment: What exactly do you call a "bytearray"? Python has lists and no arrays (and relies on duck typing).

Comment: I mean the type of bytearray in Python. For example this one: bytearray(os.urandom(1000000))

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why do you need random distribution? Wouldn't just concatenating the "small" arrays work (either separating them with a reserved value, or keeping information about their position in another structure)?

Comment: I want to create a disk image file that contains certain byte arrays. The random distribution and the voids are necessary so that file carving tools can examine this disk image file.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of disk images, but if you just need random voids ('0x0') between sequences, maybe you could just start with an empty `bytearray`, then append alternatively your fragments and empty sequences of random (strictly positive) size.

Comment: Ok good point. But the size of the large bytearray can be set by the user. So this is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following function:

```
from random import randint, shuffle
import itertools
import operator

def random_distribution(image, files):
    shuffle(files)
    available_size = len(image) - sum(map(len, files))
    gap_positions = sorted([randint(0, available_size) for i in range(len(files))])
    gap_deltas = itertools.starmap(operator.sub, zip(gap_positions, [0] + gap_positions))
    position = 0
    for file, gap_delta in zip(files, gap_deltas):
        position += gap_delta
        image[position : position + len(file)] = file
        position += len(file)
    return image
```

We randomly distribute 3 files into an image of 20 bytes for 10 times:

```
>>> files = ['abc', '1234', 'ABCDE']
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(random_distribution(bytearray(20), files).replace('\x00', '.'))
...
.abc.1234...ABCDE...
..ABCDE.abc....1234.
abcABCDE......1234..
..1234...ABCDE...abc
..1234.....abc.ABCDE
...abc.1234..ABCDE..
abc...ABCDE....1234.
.ABCDE..abc1234.....
....ABCDE..1234.abc.
1234..ABCDE.abc.....
```

The idea is to first calculate the free space by subtracting the total size of the files from the size of the image, and then randomly slice up the free space by picking random positions within the free space (which I call "gap positions"). The deltas between the gap positions will become the gaps between the files, so when we copy the files into the image, we skip the corresponding gap delta before we place a file behind the end of the last file.

Comment: I just edited the code to make it cleaner with use of zip and starmap.